# Find Match on Sheet2 from Sheet1 - Cut Match from Sheet1 to Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

New to VB and a bit lost...

I have one workbook with two sheets. I need to Compare col A on each sheet. 
If the computer name in Sheet1 Col A finds a match on Sheet2 A:A then the macro will add a line in sheet2 and add then data from Sheet1 cols A,B then del the data from Sheet1.

> Sheet1
>
> ```
>        A      |    B
> ```
>
> |EVW7LT206152 | Hug,Aman
>   |WNW7LN000000 | Impo,MrsUn
>   |EVW7LT205803 | Doe,Jane
>   |EVW7LN205817 | Doe,John
>
> ---
>
> Sheet2
>
> ```
>       A          B             C          D
> ```
>
> |EVW7LN205817| Doe,John | 12/20/2014 | 191.000.43.170
>   |EVW7LT206152| Hug,Aman | 12/20/2014 | 191.000.43.10
>   |NYW7LN000000| Impo,MrUn| 12/20/2014 | 191.000.43.197
>   |EVW7LT205803| Doe,Jane | 12/20/2014 | 191.000.43.145
>
> ---
>
> Sheet1 (Finished)
>
> ```
>      A         |      B
> ```
>
> WNW7LN000000 | Impo,MrsUn
>
> ---
>
> Sheet2 (Finished)
>
> ```
>       A          B             C          D
> ```
>
> |EVW7LN205817 | Doe,John | 12/20/2014 | 191.000.43.170
>   |EVW7LN205817 | Doe,John |            |

|EVW7LT206152 | Hug,Aman |            | 191.000.43.10
|EVW7LT206152 | Hug,Aman |            |

|NYW7LN000000| Impo,MrUn | 12/20/2014 | 191.000.43.197

|EVW7LT205803| Doe,Jane |             | 191.000.43.145
|EVW7LT205803| Doe,Jane |             |

---

This was close but does not del matches from sheet 1 like in my example.

```
Function DoOne(RowIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Key
    Dim Target
    Dim Success
    Success = False
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value) Then
        Key = Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

        Set Target = Columns(1).Find(Key, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not Target Is Nothing Then
            Rows(Target.Row).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Rows(RowIndex + 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Rows(RowIndex + 2).Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = True
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, copyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Cells(RowIndex + 3, 1).Select
            Success = True
        End If

    End If
    DoOne = Success
End Function
```

-

```
Sub TheMacro()
    Dim RowIndex As Integer
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    RowIndex = Cells.Row
    While DoOne(RowIndex)
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 3
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i am looking for Macro that I can run that will create this outcome. I have created a script that will copy the info but it will not del the original and it will stop if there is no match.

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should **always** avoid using `Select` and `Selection` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). Also, you will need to reference the sheet when using `Cells`, `Rows`, etc. when switching between sheets.

Your basic code will work, you just need to add a line to delete the row from Sheet1:

```
Function DoOne(RowIndex As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Key
    Dim Target
    Dim Success
    Success = False
    If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value) Then
        Key = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowIndex, 1).Value

        Set Target = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Find(Key, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not Target Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Target.Row).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(RowIndex + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(RowIndex + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown, copyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Target.Row).Delete
            Success = True
        End If

    End If
    DoOne = Success
End Function
```

Your sub would basically stay the same. Just delete the line that uses `Select` and add a sheet reference, and turn off screen updating to speed it up:

```
Sub TheMacro()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim RowIndex As Integer

    RowIndex = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Row
    While DoOne(RowIndex)
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 3
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```